# Реализовать кнопку добавить в избранное

Tags: javascript

Я разрабатываю приложение и работаю с api https://api.chucknorris.io, использую чистый js.

В левой колонке я радиокнопкой выбираю категорию шутки и нажимаю кнопку "Получить шутку".

Нажав сердечко необходимо добавить шутку в избранное и отобразить ее в правой колонке. У меня абсолютно нет идей, как это реализовать.

Пожалуйста, только чистый js. Спасибо.

```js
const getJoke = () => {
  let radioInput = document.querySelector(".radio__input");
  let jokes = document.querySelector(".jokes");

    let request = new Promise(() => {
      fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random")
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((data) => {
          jokes.insertAdjacentHTML(
            "afterbegin",
            showJoke(data.id, data.categories, data.value, data.updated_at)
          );
        });
    });
};

document.querySelector(".get-joke__btn").onclick = getJoke;

const showJoke = (id, category, joke, updated) => {
  return `                    <div class="joke">
                        <div class="joke__id">
                            id: <a href="https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/${id}">ID: ${id}</a><img src="../link.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="joke__text">
                            ${joke}
                        </div>
                        <div class="joke__info">
                            <div class="info__updated">
                                Last update: ${updated} hours ago
                            </div>
                            <div class="info__category">
                                ${category}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
};
```

```css
.left .container {
    max-width: 680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.right .container {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.app {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.left {
    width: 960px;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.get-joke__btn {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: linear-gradient(92.01deg, #8EA7FF 0%, #7291FF 100%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 9px 37px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jokes {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.joke {
    padding: 67px 40px 45px 100px;
    background: #F8F8F8;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.joke::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url(" https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/like.png");
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 41px;
}

.joke__id {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
}

.joke__text {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #333333;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.joke__info {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 28px;
}

.info__updated {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #ABABAB;
}

.info__category {
    margin-top: -5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #333333;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 6px 20px;
}

.right {
    width: 480px;
    background: #F8F8F8;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <section class="left">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="get-joke">
        <div class="get-joke__item">
          <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" class="radio__input" id="random" name="option" value="random">
            <label class="radio__label" for="random">Random</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="get-joke__btn">Get a joke</button>
      </div>
      <div class="jokes"></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="right">
    <div class="container">
      Favourite
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: сердечко в :after это обязательно?

Comment: @Zohid: нет, не обязательно. могу в html перенести